# Multi Dimensional array value print without any key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to print a array where I don't know the dimension of the array value. 
Now the fact is when I use `echo '<pre>'` and then `print_r($array)` it will show the `Key` and `value` with `<br>` display. 
But I want to display only the value and not the key of the array. That `$array` may contain multi-dimensional array value or single value or both.

Comment: If you have multiple keys/values in your array, would you want to display all, or just one?

Comment: For details you can visit http://www.phpfresher.com/tag/recursion-function/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use recursive function:

```
$array_list = array('a',array(array('b','c','d'),'e')); // Your unknown array
print_array($array_list);
function print_array($array_list){
    foreach($array_list as $item){
        if(is_array($item)){
            print_array($item);
        }else{
            echo $item.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this `Recursive` function

```
function print_array($array, $space="")
{
    foreach($array as $key=>$val)
    {
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            $space_new = $space." ";
            print_array($val, $space_new);
        }   
        else
        {
            echo $space." ".$val." ".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

See **[Demo](https://eval.in/182902)**

Answer (score 3):

In a short, you may use a [*recursive function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) for what you want to achieve:

```
function print_no_keys(array $array){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            print_no_keys($value);
        } else {
            echo $value, PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array-walk-recursive).

---

If you want to use indentation, then try this:

```
function print_no_keys(array $array, $indentSize = 4, $level = 0){
    $indent = $level ? str_repeat(" ", $indentSize * $level) : '';

    foreach($array as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            print_no_keys($value, $indentSize, $level + 1);
        } else {
            echo $indent, print_r($value, true), PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$a = [1, [ 2, 3 ], 4, new stdClass];

function print_no_keys(array $array, $indentSize = 4, $level = 0){
    $indent = $level ? str_repeat(" ", $indentSize) : '';

    foreach($array as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            print_no_keys($value, $indentSize, $level + 1);
        } else {
            echo $indent, print_r($value, true), PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

print_no_keys($a);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
1
    2
    3
4
stdClass Object
(
)
```